# Ruby-function for reading, parsing a text-file, removing data-duplicates

Tags: ruby, file, automation

**Task description:**
Implement a generate_unique_phone_numbers function.
The function shall parse the given text-file.

Content-example:

```
Trinidad Kemp,(838) 352-2212
Noel Bush,(647) 477-7093
Claudette Davila,(686) 868-8153
Shaun Mcbride,(433) 380-7556
Katy Blanchard,(792) 460-2468
...
```

Then return a Set with **unique** phone-numbers.
Means: **Some phone-numbers might be included multiple times.**

**My solution:**

```
require "set"

def generate_unique_phone_numbers(path)
  numbs = Set.new
  if File.exist?(path)
    lines = File.readlines(path)
    lines.each do |line|
      numbs.add line.chomp.split(",").last
    end
  else
    puts "File does not exist."
  end
  numbs
end
```

Are there any improvements concerning my solution, which should be implemented?

Would you have done it completely differently? Then how and why?

Comment: I don't understand "Some phone-numbers might be included multiple times".   This directly contradicts "return a Set with unique phone-numbers"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is how I'd do it:

```
require "set"
require "csv"

def csv_to_iterator(path)
  CSV.open(path).collect { |(_name, number)| number } 
rescue Errno::ENOENT
  []
end

def unique(iterator)
  iterator.to_set
end

def generate_unique_phone_numbers(path)
  unique(csv_to_iterator(path))
end
```

Ideally I would wrap it in a class, but for simplicity methods will do for this example.
I'm not sure how I feel about handling exception in the first method, but I decided to include it here since you have some handling in case a file doesn't exist in your example as well.

Rationale:

1. My methods are targeting an interface instead of a concrete implementation.
   So for instance, it will be easier to replace `csv_to_iterator` to something else, let's say a DB call in case our data source changes, as long as they `quack` like an `Enumerable`.
2. The methods are congruent. In the example you might return a Set or `nil` (due to `puts`), in my case I'm always returning a set, doesn't matter what. This create a coherent interface for the execution.
3. Well defined responsibilities. In the example, a single method is managing opening a file, verifying its stats, parsing, and removing duplicates. I broke down this into multiple steps and in smaller functions.